# e4 toolbar too long, doesn't make itself multiline

Tags: eclipse-rcp, toolbar, multiline, e4

My toolbar should set itself multiline, if it cannot display all of its elements.
I got lots of Tool Items in my Toolbar, but how can I set, that all of these are always displayed, i.e. in a multiline toolbar.

See the fragment.e4xmi for the model.

[my e4xmi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4grBt.png)

Comment: I don't think there is a straightforward way to split a single toolbar. I think if you have multiple toolbars in the trimbar then it will wrap between the bars.

Comment: Thank you for your approach, but this is not working. how should I add multiple ToolBars to a trimbar. For a part i can only check ToolBar, that's all...

Comment: Hi @unknown404, I too facing similar issue in my E4 based application. Did you find any solution for it

Comment: @Shashwat I am sorry, but no

Answer (score 1):

I found one way through which I am able to wrap the toolbar in e4.
Note: I found that it is wraping till 2 lines.

```
@Inject
private MTrimmedWindow mTrimmedWindow;

String toolbarID = "ID of the toolbar"
```

Now add the below code to your shell or composite's resize listener

```
MTrimBar trim = modelService.getTrim(mTrimmedWindow, SideValue.TOP);
List<MTrimElement> children = trim.getChildren();
for (MTrimElement child : children) {
    if (child instanceof MToolBar) {
        MToolBar mToolBar = (MToolBar) child;
        if (toolbarID.equals(mToolBar.getElementId())) {
            Object toolBar;
            if ((toolBar = mToolBar.getWidget()) != null && toolBar instanceof ToolBar) {
                Rectangle rect = getClientArea();
                Point size = ((ToolBar)toolBar).computeSize(rect.width, SWT.DEFAULT);
                ((ToolBar)toolBar).setSize(size);
            }
        }
    }
}
```